# EC2 instance on Amazon and I am greeted with "No space left on the disk"

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, fedora, ec2-ami

I have installed Amazon EC2 fedora instance and copying the files from one location to another.
But I am greeted with " No space left on the disk".

I did `df -f`.

with output:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              15G   15G     0 100% /
none                  312M     0  312M   0% /dev/shm
```

I want to increase the space for ec2 instance on amazon. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got a solution guys yippeeee

Assuming that you are using a linux AMI, in your case you have an easy method for increasing the size of the file system:

1) Stop the instance

2) Detach the root volume

3) Snapshot the volume

4) Create a new volume from the snapshot using the new size

5) Attach the new volume to the instance on the same place where the original one was

6) Start the instance, stop all services except ssh and set the root filesystem read only

7) Enlarge the filesystem (using for example resize2fs) and or the partition if needed

8) Reboot

As an alternative you can also launch a new instance and map the instance storage or you can create a new ami combining the two previous steps.

Comment: Will the IP change?

Comment: if it is private IP then yes. If public IP then no.

Comment: I believe stopping the instance changes the public IP. If you need to keep your IP, do your research before following these steps.

Comment: Use elastic IP to stop it from changing on reboot.

Comment: For any future searchers, here is the [Amazon guide link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/add-instance-store-volumes.html).

Answer (score 87):

Here's an even easier method. (My m2.2xlarge instance was created with RedHat Linux 6.2, I discovered it had a paltry 6gb available of it's 850gb):

1. Via ssh, check space under root: `$df -h`

> ```
> Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> /dev/xvde1              6G    6G    0G   100% /
> none                   17G     0   17G   0% /dev/shm
> ```

2. From aws console, stop the instance
3. From aws console, detach the volume (though note the mount point under attachment info, eg `/dev/sda1`)
4. From aws console, take a snapshot of the volume
5. From aws console, create a new volume using the snapshot (using all the remaining
   space for the instance type, eg 825gb in my m2.2xlarge case)
6. From aws console, attach the new volume to original mount point /dev/sda1
7. From aws console, restart the instance and ssh back in to the instance
8. From ssh, run resize2fs on the root Filesystem (see `df -h` output in step 1) [potentially not needed]

> $resize2fs /dev/xvde1

9. wait for a few minutes, possibly go and watch your buddy who is
   stopping [all the root services etc](http://www.ivarch.com/blogs/oss/2007/01/resize-a-live-root-fs-a-howto.shtml) like a boss : )
10. observe the new cavernous mount: $df -h

> ```
> Filesystem            Size  Used   Avail Use%   Mounted on
> /dev/xvde1            813G  3.7G    801G   1%     /
> none                   17G     0     17G   0%     /dev/shm
> ```

Comment: Worked great for me, didn't even need the resize2fs part. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution. Works like a charm. Step 8 is not necessary.

Comment: I followed this answer now I can't access my EC2 instance. It is saying that Site Can't Be Reach. Does anyone have an idea where I was wrong?

Comment: Even after re-attaching the volume I was still not able to do anything (because there was no space). After doing a ```sudo apt-get autoclean``` I was able to finally run ```sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1```

Comment: How do you find the mount point? I can't find attachment info either.

Answer (score 41):

Modify volume size. From AWS Console, you can modify the size of a volume.

1. From AWS console, open 'ELASTIC BLOCK STORE/Volume'
2. Select your volume and Modify volume(from Actions button)
3. Change size (e.g. 8 to 20gib)
4. Click Modify.
5. Reboot from EC2 Dashboard.
6. check size is changed by `df -h`

Comment: There is no `reboot` option in EBS modify menu!

Comment: You can reboot it from EC2 Dashboard. Click Actions button, Instance State, and Reboot. Cheers!

Comment: This seemed the easiest and less risky way of solving a disk full problem. I tried it and it worked! One thing to note is that my EC2 wouldn't reboot because it was so full, I had to instance State > Stop and then instance state > start.

Comment: I think that in case that you increase the EBS volume , it will recreate the instances

Comment: @ParoX, what do you mean by less risky? Genuine question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be the one marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

1. find the biggest files with `du -a | sort -n`
2. stop some services, they might block hidden/removed files from being finally deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I skipped all the detach/snapshot/new volume stuff... just did the resize.

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              5904748   4725152   1119608  81% /
none                  15728640         0  15728640   0% /dev/shm
[root@ip-10-25-6-214 ~]# resize2fs /dev/sda1
resize2fs 1.39 (29-May-2006)
Filesystem at /dev/sda1 is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
Performing an on-line resize of /dev/sda1 to 31457280 (4k) blocks.
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. When answering questions please add more information about your solution so that others can easily replicate your steps.

Comment: This answer is in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just code with no explanation. Please improve your answer by explaining what your code does and how it answers the question. Please read [this advice on answering programming questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I mounted the disk on another EC2 instance where I could successfully use growpart and then resize2fs. After that mounting back to the origin EC2 instance.

Comment: On the newer Nitro-based systems, this is what I had to do. I would receive an error `No space left on device` if I tried to run `growpart`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if AWS has added additional steps inorder to extend the added disk space but the below commands worked for me:

Follow the answer till the community wiki Step 6
Post that for Step 7 follow the steps as below:

1. Check whether the volume has a partition. Use the lsblk command

```
sudo lsblk
```

Output:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

xvda       202:0    0  20G  0 disk
└─xvda1    202:1    0   8G  0 part /
```

2. Check whether the partition needs to be extended. In the lsblk command output from the previous step, compare the partition size and the volume size. If the partition size is smaller than the volume size, continue to the next step. If the partition size is equal to the volume size, the partition can't be extended.
3. Extend the partition. Use the growpart command and specify the partition to extend.

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

4. Verify that the partition has been extended. Use the lsblk command. The partition size should now be equal to the volume size

```
sudo lsblk
```

Output:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0    20G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0    20G  0 part /
```

[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your case is valid when the EC2 instance was created from "EBS-Store" rather than "Instance-Store". EC2 instance created from "instance-store" will always have a huge space (around 200GB +) allocated for /mnt directory.

Otherwise your solution is valid for those EC2 machine created from "EBS-Store". You can do more with such machines.

1. Change the termination type
2. Change the instance type
3. Create an AMI from the instance
4. Auto-scale with ease.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate; ephemeral volume sizes vary according to instance size and AMI type, not [only] according to the base (instance- or ebs-store) launch type. Furthermore, the answer does not actually address the problem raised in the question, and should really have been a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you got this error

> OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

And you are using Docker containers, you can clean your EC2 instance with these commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo systemctl start docker
```