# Reduce hard drive storage of EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there any way to reduce the size of an EC2 instance? I followed the method proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151695/ec2-instace-on-amazon-and-i-am-greeted-with-no-space-left-on-the-disk), but when I tried to reduce the instance size when creating the new volume, I was prevented from doing so. The error message said that the new volume can only be of the same size or larger.

Thanks, Scott

Comment: Did you mean to reduce the size of root device of Instance? What do you mean by Instance size?

Comment: I meant the size of the root device, sorry for that. I skirted around it by just starting a new instance of the desire size, and copied all data out and into the new one. It makes sense they wouldn't want you to make root devices smaller as they make less money.

Comment: This is the very first time in my life I see the person who wanted to shrink root FS! Why did you want that?

Comment: Because I didn't knew it cost money to have a stopped instance, and I had three at 400 GB each (1200 GB, so $120 per month!) So I terminated two instances, and brought the third down to 30 GB, so that will be $3 per month.

Comment: The default is 8G and it's enough for root.

Comment: When I spin up an instance it's 2 GB.

Comment: Really? What instance type did you use?

Comment: I just used an AMI that I had made previously and started off with an m2.xlarge