# Project Android compilation failed on EC2 instance

Tags: android, ubuntu, terminal

I use an EC2 instance (Ubuntu), and I want launch gradlew in my Android project, through the Terminal.

But I have this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download artifact 'maven-ant-tasks.jar (org.apache.maven:maven-ant-tasks:2.1.3)'
   > Failed to download resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/2.1.3/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar'.
      > No space left on device
```

I checked the space, and Inodes and all is ok:

```
root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/home/mytest/sandbox/MyApplication# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       99G   12G   83G  13% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  324K   99M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /tmp
root@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx:/home/mytest/sandbox/MyApplication# df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1     6553600 241915 6311685    4% /
none            127032      2  127030    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            125790    403  125387    1% /dev
tmpfs           127032    307  126725    1% /run
none            127032      1  127031    1% /run/lock
none            127032      1  127031    1% /run/shm
none            127032      2  127030    1% /run/user
overflow        127032      4  127028    1% /tmp
```

If I download manually this jar (maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar) with wget command, the download is successful.

I tried with sudo privileges, and the same error appears (No space left on device).

Previously, I followed these explanations, to be sure about the space : [EC2 instance on Amazon and I am greeted with "No space left on the disk"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151695/ec2-instance-on-amazon-and-i-am-greeted-with-no-space-left-on-the-disk). Again, the same error appears (No space left on device).

Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: The same error shows up many times: No more space on device. Do you have space left on your instance?

Comment: Done. I followed this explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151695/ec2-instance-on-amazon-and-i-am-greeted-with-no-space-left-on-the-disk

Comment: I modified my initial problem Eric.

Comment: Do other commands in the Android toolkit succeed? Can you build with just Ant, and what is the result? You may also try a parallel install of the SDK and see what happens. I'll see, but I can't reproduce the problem.