# MySQL won't start on Bitnami EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

My EC2 instance ran out of space so followed directions to [backup and restore to a larger volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151695/ec2-instance-on-amazon-and-i-am-greeted-with-no-space-left-on-the-disk). After I did that, I couldn't start up MySQL anymore.

When I try to start MySQL on my EC2 instance with Bitnami, it just hangs there. It looks like it's because I don't have a socket file at all where it should be `/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock`. Instead I just have a lock file there (`/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.lock`).

[One source I found](https://www.hivelocity.net/kb/what-to-do-if-mysql-sock-file-is-missing/) said to recreate a symlink to another `.sock` file but I think because it's Bitnami it's in a different location and I'm not sure where that is.

Of course, it's possible that this sock file is just a red herring so I'm also digging into other possible causes. Has anyone else had this happen before? It seems like a problem that could be common but I haven't been able to find much about this aside from the [vanilla Bitnami docs](https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress/administration/control-services/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the MySQL script that Bitnami has (found at `/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh`) you can see that the MySQL log file is located at `/opt/bitnami/mysql/data/mysqld.log` on Bitnami instances. Look at the most recent logs, mine showed the following toward the end of the logs:

```
[Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): 'x.x.x.x'; port: xxxx
[Note]   - 'xxx.x.x.x' resolves to 'xxx.x.x.x';
[Note] Server socket created on IP: 'xxx.x.x.x'.
[ERROR] Unix socket lock file is empty /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.lock.
[ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Originally I thought the SSL thing was the issue but [someone else pointed out](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/mysql-failed-to-set-up-ssl.340019/) that this is just a warning.

Ultimately I was able to fix this by just backing up the lock file (just in case) and then removing it:

```
# Back that thang up
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.lock /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.lock.backup
# Remove it
sudo rm /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock.lock
# Fire it up again
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql
```